# How to compress and stitch too many SQLite files without using usual compression methods?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to stitch some SQLite files into a single big file, since it's going to be used in an embedded system with limited resources, I don't want to use huffman-based compression methods.

Does SQLite contain redundant block so I can have them removed?

Comment: I just know Navigation Data Standard(NDS) files do something like this but I don’t know how, you may find something by taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes contain redundant data. But the internal indexes used for PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints cannot be removed easily, so it might be a better idea to ship the SQL source to recreate the database, and compress that.

There is no mechanism to reduce the file size at runtime, except for using a file system with transparent compression.